# When profiling NodeJS using --inspect, what does "(program)" mean

Tags: node.js, profiling

When using `node --inspect` to profile a NodeJS application using chrome dev tools, a large part of the runtime is spent in `(program)`. I did not find information on what exactly this means? Is it just time spend in the C++ parts of NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

The `(program)` entry is Chrome itself - it's the first thing that gets executed before anything else and remains there regardless of what your Node application is doing.

There is discussion in this [Chromium profiler issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88446) on what exactly it means (and whether or not it's confusing).

You can also see in the [comments of the Changelog](https://bugs.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=179933&action=review) for the commit also includes the following comment:

> Web Inspector: [Chromium] profiler - differentiate between native code
>   (program) and idle time https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88446
>
> Reviewed by NOBODY (OOPS!).
>
> Now idleTime is supplied in profile object. In this patch, idleTime,
>   if any, is subtracted from "(program)" node, and new node "(idle)" is
>   injected as a top level node ti profile.

Comment: Chrome is not involved in this case, since I'm profiling a node.js application. (idle) would make sense, but I'm not seeing that at all. Maybe (program) means (idle) when profiling a node.js app. Maybe it's the C++ parts of node. Maybe both. I still don't really know...

Comment: You are using the chrome dev tools - how is Chrome not involved? The **thing that is doing the profiling is Chrome itself**

Comment: I'm using Chrome to profile a separate node.js application. If CPU cycles of Chrome were included in the profile, this would be so fundamentally broken that I can't believe that's what's happening...